# Is it possible to hide a single Gradle subproject from IntelliJ / Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, idea-gradle-plugin

The *Gradle* project is imported and synced with Android Studio and every single subproject is available.

### Context

Assume that `project(':core:tools')` doesn't contain any valuable information other than the `build.gradle`, but the project contains "implicit" sources shared with other subprojects.

Due to this setup I'd prefer to not have the project containing sources visible in Android Studio. Also I get the error `Duplicated content roots detected` after every sync, I'm hoping to resolve by this configuration as well.

## Example

A more specific example would be a subproject `project(':clone')` being a simple "clone" of another subproject `project(':original')`. The configuration of the `original` does matter here, but it's different to the `clone`, which just uses the sources of the `original`:

```
android.sourceSets.main {
    root "${project(':original').projectDir}/src/main"
}
```

##### Actual

[image: actual]

##### Expected

[image: expected]

It would also be okay if `clone` isn't visible here.

Comment: I guess you can replace include/includeBuild with a dependency on the JAR of that Subproject?

Comment: @romanv-jb sadly I don't think so. This subproject strongly integrates with other subprojects, consuming these and being consumed.

Comment: @tynn Can you elaborate more on the things we want to archive?
I also want to know what do you mean by hiding source visibility in android studio?

Comment: @ParthDave after a Sync I don't want Idea to know about the Gradle module. Especially the Android view should not contain the module and, even more importantly, show the sources of the module.

Comment: @tynn I know you explained it multiple times, but what you're trying to achieve is not very clear to me. Would you mind adding more detail to your question - Relevant parts of your build.gradle files, what the directory structures look like, and how the relationships between the subprojects are setup?

Comment: @RaGe I added a more specific example and screenshots of the actual and expected view in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it sounds like you are doing strange things you really, really, really shouldn't do.

But putting the blinders on and staying in the vein of doing things you really should not do, you could for example change your settings script to not `include(":clone")` if the system property `idea.sync.active` is set.

This way during an IntelliJ or AS sync it will be like if `:clone` wouldn't exist.

You probably need to also modify other places where you then refer to that project to be conditional.

Or maybe you conditionally use a different build script for `clone` during the sync or similar.

All things you most probably really should not do, but could pragmatically solve your issue at hand.